# Passing a hidden value in Jquery autocomplete in zend

Tags: php, jquery, autocomplete

How can we Pass a hidden value in Jquery autocomplete in zend ..

For ex..

if the autocomplete returns a list of locations ..
then the location id for each location is also returned as a hidden variable ..
for use on other pages ..

Comment: Good question. I did this with django and ended up doing an ajax call (in onSelect) back to the server to get the related variable (id, in your case). would be great to find a better way..

Comment: but i would like to do it with Jquery .. is it possible ?

Comment: If you're asking if jQuery has ajax http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/